# How to select values that are paired with each in a list of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with rows like this:

```
+-------------+---------+
| employee_id | role_id |
+-------------+---------+
|         850 |      10 |
|         850 |      20 |
|         850 |      30 |
|         850 |      40 |
|         851 |      10 |
|         851 |      20 |
|         851 |      40 |
|         852 |      10 |
|         852 |      30 |
+-------------+---------+
```

An employee can't have the same role multiple times as employee_id and role_id combine to form the primary key of this associative table.

I'm trying to select all employee_ids that are paired with ids 20, 30, and 40.  In other words, I want all employee_ids that have all three of those roles. In the above table, it would only be employee_id 850.  This is a little tricky for me because I want to get all of the employee_ids that match this, not just one.

Beyond my main issue, I'm trying to eventually consolidate all three of those roles into a new role, role 90. In the above case, the second, third, and fourth rows would be removed and replaced with one that had (850, 90) on it.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want all employee_id where role_id is 20, 30, or 40?

Comment: Sorry, I want all employee_id who have all three roles, not just one of them.

Comment: is it possible for an employee to have more than one of the same role id? in other words, would 853 with role_ids 10, 10, and 20 fit in your data set?

Comment: @Jenn No, as employee_id and role_id form a compound key together.  853 couldn't have 10 twice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a set-within-sets query.  Here is a solution:

```
select employee_id
from atable
where role_id in (20, 30, 40)
group by employee_id
having count(distinct role_id) = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select employee_id from empl, 
  (select employee_id e1 from empl where role_id=30) m, 
  (select employee_id e2 from empl where role_id=40) n 
where empl.role_id=20 and employee_id=m.e1 and employee_id=n.e2
```